# Как избежать задваивание строк в запросе с join

Tags: sql, postgresql

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
есть такая структура. товар может быть в нескольких категориях.

при запросе, чтобы посмотреть все товары из каталога 1 :

```
select id_product
from product_catalog_category pcc
inner join catalog_catgory cc on cc.id = pcc.id_catalog_category
inner join catalog c on c.id = cc.id_catalog
where c.id = 1
```

Происходит задвоение товара

- 5454
- 5454

как получить весь список товаров каталога без задвоений?

можно ли обойтись без group by и distinct?

Answer (score 0):

День добрый.

> есть такая структура. товар может быть в нескольких категориях.

Как понимаю у Вас связь  `многие-ко-многим` согласно условию

Ваш запрос просто выводит товар из разных категорий. Он не дублирует один и тоот же..

Как вариант

1. в строку `from product_catalog_category pcc` добавьте атрибут `UNIQUE` -  `UNIQUE(id-product)` и в конец запроса придется ставить группировку через атрибут `ORDER BY`.  не помню момент где ставить `ORDER BY` до `WHERE`или после. Просто есть два атрибута для групировки. Один ДО, второй ПОСЛЕ ставится.
2. второй вариант , на мой взгляд представленная ниже модель будет соответствовать условию. Так как вы имеете много КАТАЛОГов - таблица, КАТЕГОРИЯ совместима с многими продуктами и ПРОДУКТОВ много в категории, создайте промежуточную таблицу `product_catalog_category`.

В промежуточной таблице и собираете всех. Просто получаете больше маневренности.
На промежуточной таблице и фильтруете  `where c.id = 1`

Не знаю как тут загрузить файл для ска чивания. Но, возможно [эти шпаргалки](https://disk.yandex.ru/d/QgZKcCLCJJRhJw) помогут с запросами

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: модель уже существует, к сожалению изменить невозможно.

про ```from ... unique(id)```  впервые слышу... попробую

Comment: unique - из всего списка оставляет только уникальные значения.

Comment: > можно ли обойтись без group by и distinct?
Используйте оконные функции - row_number().

Comment: Tryd0g0lik, может, вы имеете в виду все-таки distinct?

Comment: ~SELECT DISTINCT поле FROM имя_таблицы WHERE условие~  или ~  SELECT UNIQUE * FROM Region_Sales ~ Суть в том, что есть атрибут позволяющий получить уникальное значение из выборки.  иначе ни как при данных условиях/ Попробуйте с DISTINCT

https://www.1keydata.com/sql/sql-select-unique.html


https://www.schoolsw3.com/sql/sql_unique.php

Comment: у меня ограничение на distinct, тк в select есть поле типа json с которым distinct не работает((

Comment: а что со вторым вариантом - unique ?

Comment: с unique - шибка при выполнении запроса. это,наврное, для mySql. мне нужно для postgreSql

Comment: Должен признать, что сам не нашел атрибут unique в SELECT .

Тогда без группировки ни как . Вот решение такого же  вопроса https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/175378